# Shared objects of dependencies of a Bazel target

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build a shared object .so using Bazel.
The target is a `cc_library` and using `bazel build <target>`, I can successfully recover the shared object.

My problem arises when I try to use the shared object in another library (built with CMake). Since the target has many dependencies the linker cannot find all the symbols in the .so and the linking phase fails.
I'm trying to recursively built all the missing dependencies with Bazel adding explicitly the targets of dependencies to the command `bazel build`.

This manual work is very long, pedantic and wasteful since Bazel is already capable to resolve dependencies automatically and probably it builds internally all the needed shared objects.

Do you know if there is a way to recover the .so files of the dependencies of a target built with Bazel?

Comment: Have you tried `ldd`?

Comment: `ldd` output seems incomplete. I'm trying to build a target of Tensorflow C++ library and the output of `ldd` on such a target is just

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff9f69000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0adde34000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0addd4d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0addd2d000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0addb21000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0ade0b4000)

Comment: @LGrementieri were you ever able to find out how to get the complete list of dependencies with LDD? If we compile the cc_library as cc_binary it works, it seems to be something about how Bazel links shared libraries.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember after more than one year. Sorry :(